# Crash app libc++abi.dylib (Admob)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Hello have crash app in IOS

This log:

```
2015-01-15 13:23:32.490 App[23898:1611888] <Google> Category methods are not loaded. Make sure you link the Google Mobile Ads library using one of the -ObjC, -force_load, or -all_load linker flags. See https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/#ios for more information.
2015-01-15 13:23:34.526 App[23898:1611888] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: is not supported in iOS 8.0 and later.
2015-01-15 13:23:34.802 App[23898:1611888] +[NSDecimalNumber gad_negativeOne]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x7d7400
2015-01-15 13:23:34.805 App[23898:1611888] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[NSDecimalNumber gad_negativeOne]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x7d7400'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x03278946 __exceptionPreprocess + 182
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x02be0a97 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x03280465 +[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 277
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x031c93e7 ___forwarding___ + 1047
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x031c8fae _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   App                         0x000872ea -[GADStatisticDictionary decrementNumberForKey:shouldNotifyDelegate:] + 58
    6   App                          0x0007cc75 -[GADApplication init] + 512
    7   App                         0x0007ca45 __35+[GADApplication sharedApplication]_block_invoke + 55
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x03ecde2f _dispatch_client_callout + 14
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x03eb876c dispatch_once_f + 363
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x03eb85fc dispatch_once + 31
    11  App                          0x0007ca0c +[GADApplication sharedApplication] + 113
    12  App                         0x000780cd +[GADSlot initialize] + 67
    13  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x02be1461 _class_initialize + 576
    14  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x02be9fe5 lookUpImpOrForward + 339
    15  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x02be9e8d _class_lookupMethodAndLoadCache3 + 55
    16  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x02bf412f objc_msgSend + 139
    17  App                          0x00075f6a -[GADBannerView commonInitWithAdSize:] + 42
    18  App                          0x0007626e -[GADBannerView initWithCoder:] + 163
    19  UIKit                               0x00c5205e -[UIClassSwapper initWithCoder:] + 239
    20  UIKit                               0x00de7f1a UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 739
    21  UIKit                               0x00de7c2f -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 371
    22  UIKit                               0x00c51bf1 -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:] + 189
    23  UIKit                               0x00de7f1a UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 739
    24  UIKit                               0x00de811c UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1253
    25  UIKit                               0x00de7c2f -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 371
    26  UIKit                               0x00c50ea7 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1164
    27  UIKit                               0x00a73624 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 270
    28  UIKit                               0x00a73dbb -[UIViewController loadView] + 295
    29  UIKit                               0x00a73fef -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 78
    30  UIKit                               0x00a74595 -[UIViewController view] + 35
    31  UIKit                               0x0096b825 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 66
    32  UIKit                               0x0096bc99 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 287
    33  UIKit                               0x0096bf50 -[UIWindow _orderFrontWithoutMakingKey] + 49
    34  UIKit                               0x0097a28d -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 80
    35  UIKit                               0x00917776 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 3108
    36  UIKit                               0x0091ac0d -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1639
    37  UIKit                               0x009337d0 __84-[UIApplication _handleApplicationActivationWithScene:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 59
    38  UIKit                               0x0091981f -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 155
    39  FrontBoardServices                  0x05b799de __37-[FBSWorkspace clientEndTransaction:]_block_invoke_2 + 71
    40  FrontBoardServices                  0x05b7946f __40-[FBSWorkspace _performDelegateCallOut:]_block_invoke + 54
    41  FrontBoardServices                  0x05b8b425 __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke + 26
    42  CoreFoundation                      0x0319c1c0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 16
    43  CoreFoundation                      0x03191ad3 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 195
    44  CoreFoundation                      0x03191238 __CFRunLoopRun + 936
    45  CoreFoundation                      0x03190bcb CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 443
    46  CoreFoundation                      0x031909fb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    47  UIKit                               0x009191e4 -[UIApplication _run] + 571
    48  UIKit                               0x0091c8b6 UIApplicationMain + 1526
    49  App                          0x0005991d main + 141
    50  libdyld.dylib                       0x03ef9ac9 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to add **-ObjC** to *Other Linker Flags* in the *Build Settings* tab.

Comment: Have add , but have same error and have this : 0xb3a0c:  jmp    0xb39e3                   ; +[GADApplication sharedApplication] + 72

Comment: Did you respect the case of **-ObjC** ? Can you make a screenshot to show us what your *Linking* section in the *Build Settings* looks like ? Did you follow the official step by step guide to integrate the **Google Ads SDK** [here](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/#ios) ?